# SQL Server Autonumber or @@identy or a.n. Other

Tags: sql-server

I have suddenly had an older system landed back in my lap and currently having to cast my mind back about 6 years.

The system is accessed from 3 different offices and as such each users from these offices should get issued with the next number in sequence for there bit of work.

I have a vague recollection that it was better to use one or the other from the subject line to get a unique reference, as it was possible for the users both to make requests and both get the same reference back, but only one of them would have their record information stored, even though both external applications will say they have the right details and reference

Does this ring any bells with anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement is completed,
>   @@IDENTITY contains the last identity value that is generated by the
>   statement. If the statement did not affect any tables with identity
>   columns, @@IDENTITY returns NULL. If multiple rows are inserted,
>   generating multiple identity values, @@IDENTITY returns the last
>   identity value generated. If the statement fires one or more triggers
>   that perform inserts that generate identity values, calling @@IDENTITY
>   immediately after the statement returns the last identity value
>   generated by the triggers. If a trigger is fired after an insert
>   action on a table that has an identity column, and the trigger inserts
>   into another table that does not have an identity column, @@IDENTITY
>   returns the identity value of the first insert. The @@IDENTITY value
>   does not revert to a previous setting if the INSERT or SELECT INTO
>   statement or bulk copy fails, or if the transaction is rolled back.

(from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx))

"Autonumber" is a Microsoft Access thing.  The SQL Server equivalent is

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 othercolumn varchar (20)
)
```

For more recent versions of SQL Server (2012 and up) you can also use a [sequence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh407114.aspx).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ExampleSequence
  AS BIGINT
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 99999
  NO CYCLE
  CACHE 10;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Example
(ExampleId INT NOT NULL,
AnotherColumn VARCHAR(10))
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Example
ADD DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ExampleSequence FOR ExampleId
GO
```

Which is a long way of saying that I think you're talking about two different things.

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL 2000 for info

Hi Katherine, thanks for your reply. I appreciate what you say about two different items (autonumber - access and Identity). I was trying (and failed) to try for distinguishing the two different items without using the "identity" word again.

Basically the SP for this DB first inserts the data and then calls @@identity. My issue was that two users in two different offices were getting the same sequence back for their separate records.

Finally tracked it down and your excerpt above was really helpful in focusing my tracing.

Just for info. When the SP is initially called the first record is written to the DB and before it gets a chance for its call to the @@identity  some other inserts are carried out by other offices and incriminating the Identity column, so when it finally executes (and the same for all offices) the latest write is the identity that gets returned.

Thankfully all data is secure and it's just it's identifier that is screwed up. Which we have other processes that catch it, which have just kicked and brought this to our attention.

Off to create a defect now and see how long it takes them to fix it :)